# Concurrent read and write to BlockingQueue

Tags: java, queue, blockingqueue

I'm using a LinkedBlockingQueue in front of a database. One thread writes to the queue and another one reads from the queue.

Two concurrent writes should not be possible I think. But is it possible that one thread writes and the other thread reads at the same time from the queue? And if not, is there a queue providing this in Java?

Comment: Yes. `LinkedBlockingQueue` is not simply a synchronized `LinkedList`.

Comment: You can just read the javadoc, it all is discussed in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that one thread is **reading** and one is **writing** at the same time.

`LinkedBlockingQueue` uses two locks for this purpose. One for taking items from queue and other for putting items.

```
/** Lock held by put, offer, etc */
private final ReentrantLock putLock = new ReentrantLock();

/** Lock held by take, poll, etc */
private final ReentrantLock takeLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

The way of implementation on `LinkedBlockingQueue` is also discussed in its [source file (line 77)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#77).

```
/*
 * A variant of the "two lock queue" algorithm.  The putLock gates
 * entry to put (and offer), and has an associated condition for
 * waiting puts.  Similarly for the takeLock.  The "count" field
 * that they both rely on is maintained as an atomic to avoid
 * needing to get both locks in most cases. Also, to minimize need
 * for puts to get takeLock and vice-versa, cascading notifies are
 * used. When a put notices that it has enabled at least one take,
 * it signals taker. That taker in turn signals others if more
 * items have been entered since the signal. And symmetrically for
 * takes signalling puts. Operations such as remove(Object) and
 * iterators acquire both locks.
 */
```